# How to add custom line endings in text file (e.g. I want to add a line ending after all periods)

Tags: c++, c, text, newline, text-files

I have a bunch of text files where I want to add a line ending after each period.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this by doing replacing all periods with a \n\n, assuming I have the right encoding (unix).

Anyone know how I would do this? Replace .'s with .\n\n and then save as a different file?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tag this question with `C++` for a particular reason?

Comment: Smells a bit like homework to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -pne 's/\./\.\n/g' < input_file > output_file
```

Comment: The switches `-p` and `-n` are mutually exclusive, but as the man page says, "A -p overrides a -n switch."

Answer (score 1):

`sed s/\\./.\\n\\n/g file > newfile`

You might want `sed s/\\.\ */.\\n\\n/g file > newfile` which will get rid of whitespace trailing periods.

Answer (score 1):

Igor Krivokon had it right, but it can be improved as

```
perl -p -i.orig -e 's/\./\.\n/g' input_files ...
```

which takes any number of input files, edits them in-place and stores the original in `input_file.orig` as a backup. If you don't want backups, use a bare `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are insisting on doing it in `C`, you could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE *inFile, *outFile;
  int c;
  inFile=fopen("infile.txt","r");
  outFile=fopen("outfile.txt","w"); 
  if (inFile==NULL || outFile==NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
  else
  {
    while((c = fgetc(inFile)) != EOF){
      if (c == '.'){
        fputc('\n',outFile);
        fputc('\n',outFile);
      }else{
        fputc(c, outFile);
      }   

    } 
    fclose (inFile);
    fclose (outFile);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy but slow method:
1. Open source file for reading.
2. Open target file for writing.
3. While not EOF of source file:
3.1.  read char from source file.
3.2.  write char to target file.
3.3.  if char == '.' then write "\n\n" to target file.
3.4. End-while
4. Close target file.
5. Close source file.

A faster method is to allocate a bufer, read into the buffer and parse for '.'. Write all chars up to and including the '.'.   Write some newlines.  Parse some more.  Read more, and repeat until EOF.

Comment: Why not regexp? This is tedious and unnecessary.

Comment: This is simple to implement.  Doesn't require extra effort to understand regexp nor extra development time to implement a library external to the language.  Even Boost sometimes requires extra effort to implement.